# Create homepage that routes to separate router component (Angular 2)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, router

I am not able to post image because I need at least 10 reputation:
Please refer to this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCwAP.jpg

I am fairly new to Angular 2. I have working routing system that directs the user to different components. What I have came up with represents 'Page 2' of the image provided. I want to implement 'Page 1' of the image provided that routes me to the 'Page 2' functionality I already have. The code is as follows:

This is my code for app.routing.ts:

```
import {ModuleWithProviders} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {ClientsComponent} from "./clients.component";
import {EClientsComponent} from "./eclients.component";
import {RClientsComponent} from "./rclients.component";
import {KnockoutsComponent} from "./knockouts.component";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";

const appRoutes: Routes = [
{
path: '',
component: ClientsComponent
},
{
path:'migrated',
component: ClientsComponent
},
{
path: 'eligible',
component: EClientsComponent
},
{
path: 'review',
component: RClientsComponent
},
{
path: 'knockouts',
component: KnockoutsComponent
},
{
path: '**',
component: ClientsComponent
}

];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

My app.component.hmtl is as follows:

```
<div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" id="nav">
          <adp-button iconType="home" buttonStyle="primary"     routerLink="/migrated">Migrated Clients</adp-button>
          <adp-button buttonStyle="primary" routerLink="/knockouts">Client   Migration</adp-button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This in essence is 'Page 2' of the image provided.
This code is working properly and can reach all paths.
What I want to implement next is 'Page 1' of the image displayed. I want the user to be able to log in first, and then be routed to 'Page 2' that I have already implemented. I want to create a 'HomeComponent' for this application. Then I want to Route to the 'ClientComponent' that is currently the homepage and have everything working as is. Please help with this I would appreciate it.

Let me know if you have any further questions

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you want to add another route for your login page, and hide the navbar on this route, right? You already know how to add routes, so that shouldn't be a problem. The router service allows getting the url, so you should be able to use *ngIf to hide the navbar if the url is the url of the login page. You could also make all your routes expect the login route children of a parent route conteining the navbar and a second router-outlet

Comment: See http://plnkr.co/edit/kVcNB8aXiAr1yyAXbsIM?p=preview for a demo of the second strategy

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for your help I tried the second method and it worked perfectly. I really appreciate it